# Clicking on link with onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

Good day, I made a link in html

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="next(1)" id="next"></a>
```

If i click on it nothing happens. Can't use href="#" and that also doesn't work. But If I call next(1) in console it does work.

Comment: How does `function next` look like ? Is it under `global scope` ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VE9FYTDr As I said I can call it from console and it works.

Comment: It seems incomplete example to me.. Do share a fiddle...

Comment: The website is completely made using foreach php function. Do you think that would be great idea? http://dodiaklukac.eu/banska-bystrica.php If you click on picture you have red and blue box. I need to use blue box and it doesn't work

Comment: I think your browser rendered HTML/parsed HTML will help to execute this code..

Comment: Post how you are using next func (syntax)

Comment: pastebin.com/VE9FYTDr

Comment: I've removed the "[SOLVED]" from the title, by accepting an answer the site will automatically show the question as resolved, no need to change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function "next()" already exists in javascript so it can't be called. Renamed to nextone() works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

> `Event-handler` specified `inline` expects function to be under `global-scope`

```js
function next(id) {
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="next(1)" id="next">Element</a>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this has something to do with my question.

Comment: @KubaJanek – If _NO,_ do analyze your question so that one can understand it better...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not use capital case and use just `onclick`.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="next(1);" id="next"></a>

   <script>
       function next(value){
        alert(value);
       }
   </script>
```

Comment: Yeah. But it repairs itself everytime as I see in console.

Comment: I tried even like you said. Nothing special happend.

Comment: Test on button tag as well <button onclick="next(1);">Click me</button>

Comment: Please remove the id='next' maybe you have another id called next

Comment: Yes I have another id="next". That has nothing to do with that. I am using foreach() so there is not workaround

Comment: Please use always unique id in your html page and remove the duplicate ids.

Comment: I am sure the problem is with duplicate ids, because javascript is very sensitive with element id

Comment: but you are not right. I have a lot of duplicates and there it works fine